# Resizing ListView when keyboard is present

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a little problem with resizing my listview when software keyboard is present. Basically I am using Google maps API where the map covers the whole screen, with transparent actionbar, and I have a list of vehicles present on the map in a fragment which slides in from the right side. When right panel is out whole layout looks like this:[image]

Now I am using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` so when I focus edit text and keyboard slides out, it looks like this: [image]

Which is not good because I can not see whole list of vehicles. I have tried using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`, but since I am using transparent actionbar this happens:[image]
I can see whole listView and it is scrolling nicely, but my EditText is now under the ActionBar. Basically what I want to achieve is a combination of both cases so it will look like this:[image]
Now this is layout for fragment with my list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    tools:context="hidden">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/vehicle_search_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_vehicles"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vehicle_search_edit_text"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is layout of my MainActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_root_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_root_vehicles"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_root_settings"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am familiar with setting height of layout programmatically, since I am already doing it with layout in which listfragment is nested. ActionBar must stay transparent because that is how my boss wants it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that because your actionbar is similar to the one used by Google Maps for example, the space normally occupied by it is considered available for use by other layouts, in your case, the fragment. You cound try and specify a padding or margin for your fragment container, something like :

```
android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

(the size of the actionbar).

Together with

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

this should work.

It the padding value does not satisfy you, manually provide a more appropriate value.

Comment: i had to alter my MainActivity.xml and change alignParentBottom to alignParentTop, but this works, so I am marking this as an answer, thank you

Comment: Did it work with android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize or did you have to change the value? I am asking because I didn't get the chance to test this myself.

Comment: yes, it works perfectly,  can't believe i didn't figure this out myself

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file, add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in in your activity.
For example,

```
<activity
            android:name="com.sample.ListViewsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
```

I think, this solves your problem. Just try it out.

Comment: I am using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` right now and it looks like second picture, I have stated this in my question, so this is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

API says the following
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL = The list will automatically scroll to the bottom, no matter what items are currently visible.

setTranscriptMode(int mode) = Puts the list or grid into transcript mode.

Please test , see if it works !

```
setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
```

.

Answer (score 0):

in AndroidManifest.xml  add:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"/>
</activity>
```

for your activity
and add two parameters:

```
<ListView
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="normal"/>
```